# display menu doesn't show all options

Tags: 14.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, display-manager

I'm using two displays and for some reason I don't have the entire display menu. Is there some way to restore this (or change the usual settings with dconf editor or terminal)?

I'm using ubuntu gnome 14.04 with gnome shell 3.10.4.

What I have
[image: What I have]

What I want
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal:
**xrandr -q** show your connected displays on ports, then assuming your primary display is DP1 and secondary HDMI1
**xrandr --output HDMI1 --right-of DP1**

To make xrandr changes permanent :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236686

or make file in **/etc/X11/Xsession.d/**
e.g *45custom_settings* and paste
xrandr --output HDMI1 --right-of DP1

You can also set your primary display with this (assuming you want displayport 1) :
xrandr --output DP1 --primary

Comment: that's nice and all but I already know that....I want a way to access the extra options like sticky edges and the launcher placement